# Loading pickled model with Pyspark

Tags: scikit-learn, pyspark, pickle

I'm trying to load a pickled model from S3 using PySpark, then make a prediction using the model. I can load the model all right, but when I try to feed the model to the method that makes the prediction, I am running into `PicklingError: Cannot pickle files that are not opened for reading` I've read the docs on what can and cannot be pickled, but I can't seem to find the bug.

The code that loads the model:

```
    rdd_pickle = spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles(model_path_in_s3)
    l = rdd_pickle.collect()
    pickle_text = l[0][1]
    self.model = pickle.loads(pickle_text)
```

The method where the model makes predictions:

```
def turn_labeller(convo):
    """Annotate a conversation with turn labels.

    :param convo: Conversation whose turns haven't been labelled.
    :type convo: list of dict
    :param model: CRF model used to predict turn labels
    :type model: sklearn-crfsuite.CRF 
    :return: The convo, now with labelled turns
    :rtype: list of dict
    """
    turn_features = [extract_turn_features(i, convo) for i in range(len(convo))]

    predicted_labels = model.predict_single(turn_features)
    for i,turn in enumerate(convo):
        if i == 0:
          turn["previous_turn_label"] = "__ROOT__"
        else:
          turn["previous_turn_label"] = predicted_labels[i-1]
        turn["turn_label"] = predicted_labels[i]
    return convo
```

And the method for doing all the calculations:

```
    def run(self):
    """Run the pipeline."""
    # Ok, so next thing is to run our transformations
    rdd_tagged = (
        self.rdd_interactions
        .filter(lambda d, valid=self.filter_invalid_thread_id: "Thread ID" in d.keys() and valid(d["Thread ID"]))
        .filter(lambda d, config=self.regex_configs: d["Thread ID"] not in config["BadThreads"])
        .map(lambda d: (d["Thread ID"], d))
        .groupByKey()
        .map(lambda t: list(t[1]))  # Now all interactions per conversation are together
        .filter(lambda ld: len(ld) > 0)
        .map(lambda ld, clean_conv=self.clean_conversation: clean_conv(ld))
        .filter(lambda d: d is not None)
        .filter(lambda d: d["conversation"])  # remove conversations without content
        .map(lambda d, segment=self.turn_segmentation, conf=self.regex_configs: segment(d, conf))
        .flatMap(lambda ld, label=self.turn_labeller: label(ld))
    )
```

Everything runs until the last flatMap with the call to turn_labeller. What is it about that call that's causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, my problem was just that I didn't add a @staticmethod decorator above the definition of the turn_labeller method. An easy fix.